# Meaning of curly brackets in $x\mapsto \{x\}$ vs. $x\mapsto x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have the following:

> The mapping $f: A \rightarrow B$ is defined by $x\mapsto \{x\}$.

I understand the meaning of the notation $f:A \rightarrow B$. For instance, if the sets are $A=\mathbb R$ and $B=\mathbb R$, we can have the function $ f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, defined by $x\mapsto f(x)=x$. So if $x=4$ we have $f(4)=4$, etc.

But what is the meaning of the curly brackets around $x$? I.e. what is the difference between
$$
f: A \rightarrow B, \quad x\mapsto \{x\} \tag 1
$$
and
$$
f: A \rightarrow B, \quad x\mapsto x \tag 2
$$
?

**Update:**

The notation $\{x\}$ is from the [proof of Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem#Proof). Here the co-domain is the power set. I'm not interested in this specific proof, so I tried to simplify my question because I'm just stuck at $\{x\}$. Does my question still make sense if the co-domain isn't a power set?

Comment: If you've ever seen something like $\{1,2,3\}$, it's the same curly brackets.

Comment: The function is $f: \mathbb R\to P(\mathbb R)$.  THe input is a real number.  Then output is a set.

Comment: If $f:A\to B$ and $f(x)=\{x\}$.  then the co domain must be a set that contains the sets $\{x\}$ as elements.  Theoretically $B$ doesn't *need* to be $P(A)$ but it's strongly implies $P(A) \subset B$.  But we don't actually need *all* of $P(A)$.  But we do need for $\{$all single element subsets of $A\}\subset B$. For $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ then $f(x) =\{x\}$ doesn't make a lick of sense because $\{$all single element subsets of $\mathbb R\}\not\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: If you had $A=\{cat,dog, elephant\}$ and $B= \{\{1,2\},\{7,12,19\}, \{6\},\{5\}\}$ would $f(cat)=\{5\}; f(dog)=\{6\}; f(elephant)=\{6\}$. Would that make sense? Or if $A=\{cat,dog, elephant\}$ and $B=P(A)$ adn $f(cat) = \{cat\}$ and $f(dog) = \{dog\}$ and $f(elephant)=\{elephant\}$ would that make sense?  I fear you are overthinking.  $f$ is simply a function that maps elements of $A$ to sets.  And $B$ is a co-domain that has those sets as elements.  There's nothing strange or mysterious about having the output of a function being a set.

Answer (score 5):

In the linked set-theoretic context, the meaning is that $\{x\}$ is the *singleton* of $x$, a set of which $x$ is the only member.

Comment: Just curious: if we were to study the preimage of $\{p\}$ (under some map $f$), would it be correct to read $f^{-1}[\{p\}]$ as “the preimage of the singleton of $p$”? The only reason I ask is because I’ve heard mathematicians say “the preimage of a $p$”, and after reading your answer, I’m assuming they mean $f^{-1}[\{p\}]$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon Basically, yes. In general, square brackets indicate a set-to-set mapping, defined in the obvious way in terms of a function that uses round brackets.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps you are confused with the notation for a single element set?  If a set contains four elements, $a,b,c,d$, we notate the set as: $\{a,b,c,d\}$.  If a set contains three elements $b,c,d$, we notate the set as: $\{b,c,d\}$.  If a set contains two elements, $c,d$, we notate the set as: $\{c,d\}$.  And if a set contains *one* element, $d$, then we notate the set as: $\{d\}$.  That's all.  (BTW, a set with no elements is often written as $\{\}$; but most people find $\emptyset$ easier to read.)

.....

$f:A\to B$ so that $f(x) = \{x\}$ means it takes the object $x$ as input and outputs a set; $\{x\}$.

There's nothing weird or mysterious about this.

But it *does* require that if $W = \{\Omega \in \mathscr P(A): |\Omega| = 1\} = \{\{x\}: x \in A\} =\{$ subsets of $A$ with exactly on element$\}$, then $W \subset B$.

If $W \not \subset B$ then that makes no sense and is not possible.  It is impossible for the same reason $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, $f(n) = \sqrt n$ is impossible, or $f: \mathbb R \to \{elephants\}$, $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is impossible, or that $f:\{$people in Arizona$\}\to \{$Italian dishes$\}$, $f(x)= x$'s favorite meal, is impossible.  [because the square root of every natural number aren't in the codomain of natural numbers; because the square root of a real number is not an elephant so is not in the codomain of a elephants, and there are people in Arizona whose favorite meal need not be Italian.]

presumably, in this case, and you confirm it in your update,  $B = \mathscr P(A)$.

In which case $f:A \to \mathscr P(A)$ via $f(x) = \{x\}$ makes perfect sense:  $f$ is the function that takes an element of $A$ and returns the set containing precisely that element.

Answer (score 0):

It is often used as the notation for "fractional part", i.e.

$$ \{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor $$

Check to see if this is not the convention defined previously in the notes or other material you are reading.

Added (in view of edit to Question, adding context):  In the Wikipedia article discussing Cantor's Thm., the curly braces simply mean "set builder" notation, i.e. $\{ x \}$ is the singleton set containing $x$ and only $x$.

Comment: Hi! I don't know so I updated the question with a link.

Comment: The link you give seems to be clear in using $\{ x \}$ to mean the singleton set containing $x$.  Isn't that notation familiar to you?

Comment: In my experience, the phrase "set builder" is reserved for things like $\{x\in\mathbb R:x^2=1\}$ or $\{x^2:x\in\mathbb R\}$. I'd just call $\{x,y\}$ "set notation".

Comment: @MarkS.: I take your point, but [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) seems to me to lump both "the roster method" (enumerating the elements of a set) and delineating a set's membership with a predicate as types of set builder notation.

Answer (score 0):

"$x \mapsto $x" is just the identity map - it takes $x$ to $x$.

"$x \mapsto ${x}" takes $x$ to a set with only one element, that element being $x$.

In response to your update: It would *not* make sense in general -- the co-domain has to be a set whose elements are sets (which **is** the case for the power set).

Are you comfortable with sets like that? They can be confusing when you first meet them. For example, are $\{5,6\}$ and $\{\{5,6\}\}$ the same set? (Answer: No.) How many elements do they have? (Answer: 2 and 1, respectively.)

Comment: "the co-domain has to be a set whose elements are sets"  Well, nit-pick, has to be a set with *some* of its elements being sets.  And it must contain *all* the single element subsets of the domain as elements.